# キャラクターに壁を走らせたい

Tags: unity3d, game-development

実現したいことは、ジェットコースターの垂直ループのようなコースをキャラクターに走らせることです。

**参考動画(GIF)**

```html
<img src="https://img.gifmagazine.net/gifmagazine/images/1386312/original.gif" width="320" />
```

**試したこと**

壁の法線ベクトルを取得してその逆方向に重力をかけてあげればできるかなと思いましたが、キャラクターが落ちてしまいます。

アプローチの仕方が悪いのでしょうか？解決策を探しています。よろしくお願いいたします。

```cs
    Ray ray = new Ray(playerObj.transform.position, Vector3.down);

    int layerMask = 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Wall");

        RaycastHit raycastHit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out raycastHit, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask))
        {

            playerObj.transform.eulerAngles =
                Quaternion.FromToRotation(raycastHit.transform.up, raycastHit.normal).eulerAngles;
            GravityVector = playerObj.transform.rotation * Vector3.down;
                    
            PlyaerRB = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            PlyaerRB.useGravity = false;
        }
        
void update(){
        PlyaerRB.AddForce(GravityVector * 9.81f, ForceMode.Acceleration);
}
```

Comment: 遠心力を計算して、それを重力とすれば良いのではないでしょうか？　（重力と遠心力を合成した力がかかるのですが、(物理学的に)正しくしようとすると、垂直ループに侵入する速度が遅いとループの途中で墜落するとか、いろいろ面倒くさい事が起きるのでループ中だけ例外的に扱うのも手かと）

Comment: ぱっとみ考え方自体は良さそうなので、本当にrayがWallに当たっているか、GravityVectorの方向が想定通りか確認してみてください

Comment: お二方回答ありがとうございました！

takemori_kondoさん
作成したコースターの曲線が角ばっていて
そこの角に衝突することによって
余計な方向へ力が加わっていたことが原因でした

Fumu 7さん
重心の計算は
private Rigidbody rb;
rb.centerOfMass = GravityVector;
みたいな感じでよいでしょうか？